# signal processing + finance?

Tags: finance, career, general, algorithm

I am a postgrad student doing a master in Signal Processing and I have graduated from an engineering school
I was wondering if there are any jobs in finance that are opened to people having this kind of background? I don't know much about finance but I've seen the words "algorithmic trading" or "HF trading" thrown around a few times and I'm wondering if it's not something that is related to signal processing? Or would I need to have a more specific degree?
thanks